# Should there be a single policy for rep on meta/main site across the SO network?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

As everyone (reading this post) knows, your SO rep is different from your SO meta rep.

On other sites, such as Programmers, your meta rep *is* your main site rep.

Shouldn't there be a single, consistent policy across all sites?

One solution would be to have a single meta rep on all meta sites.

Comment: There will be soon(ish) there are plans to split MSO into a proper meta for Stack Overflow and Meta.StackExchange where network issues can be discussed.

Comment: @ChrisF Is there a place where I can read about these kinds of upcoming changes and educate myself?  If so please provide a link.

Comment: Here is where you learn about such things. I can't find the link right now though - sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta StackOverflow is special. It acts as both SO's meta site **and** the meta site for all of Stack Exchange. Because of that, it really is more of a regular SE site than a meta-site. Therefore, it has its own separate reputation.

There are plans to split it up into two sites: a regular SE site (for dealing with suggestions and discussion for all of SE) and SO's meta-site. At which point, it will work like a regular meta-site.

Comment: So at that point your SO rep and your SO meta rep will be the same?  (And your current SO meta rep will migrate to the new "SE meta" site?)

Comment: `Meta StackOverflow is special` - In more than one ways ;P

Comment: @ScottWilson Yes.

Comment: So where do the unicorns go?